# Get URL parameter after clean URL .htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using the .htaccess below to *clean* a URL from `http://example.com/tutorial?id=hello` to `http://example.com/tutorial/hello` (change **?id=** to **/**)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tutorial/([^/\.]+)/?$ tutorial.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The problem is that after the rewrite I can't get the id parameter anymore:

PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
echo $_GET['id'];
}
```

What do I need to change to get the id parameter after the rewrite?

Comment: it should work. Are you sure that the rewrite rule actually work?

Comment: You should not need to change anything for the query string parameters to work with a rewrite engine rule. At the time PHP is run, the URL has been "translated" from `tutorial/hello` to `tutorial?id=hello`.